# Calculate earnings by giving hourly employees time and a half for hours over 40 and wage times hour

Tags: java, eclipse

```
    class HourlyEmployee extends Employee{

double wage;
double hours;
int numberOfHourly;


public HourlyEmployee(String name, String id, double wage, double hours){

}
public String toString(){
    return "ID" + employeeID + "Last Name: " + lastName;

}
public double earnings(){
    if ( hours <= 40){

    }
    return hours;

}
```

Calculate earnings by giving hourly employees time and a half for hours over 40 and wage times hours. Help please really confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The earnings are the total number of hours times wage. The total number of hours is the hours under 40 plus 1.5 the hours over 40 or the total number of hours plus 0.5 the hours over 40. Here is a sample implementation:

```
public double earnings(){
    double adjustedHours = hours;
    // For hours over 40, add 1/2 time to make it 1 1/2 time total
    if (hours >= 40){
        adjustedHours = adjustedHours + 0.5 * (hours - 40)
    }
    return adjustedHours * wage;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So my adjustedHours is numberOfhourly?

Comment: or is numberfHourly not used?

Comment: I think it is not used. It is an int and the adjusted number of hours needs to be a floating type since hours is a floating type and you might then multiple a portion of it by .5.